# Select cyrillic character in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

When user insert Russian word like 'пример' to database,database saves it like '??????'. If they insert with 'N' letter or I select it with 'N' letter, ie; exec Table_Name N'иытание' there is no problem. But I don't want to use 'N' in every query, so is there any solution for this? I will use stored procedure by the way.

**UPDATE:**

Now I can use Russian letters with alter collation. But I can't alter collation for every language and I just want to learn is there any trigger or function for automatic add N in front of the text after text add. IE; when I insert 'пример', SQL should take it like N'пример' autamaticly.

Comment: Keep column data type as NVARCHAR instead of VARCHAR

Comment: What do you mean that you don't want to use `N'text'` in every query?  This is the way to specify that a string literal is Unicode... If you have a parameterised query, declare the variables as `NVARCHAR` (as suggested by @PareshJ) and this will solve your problem.

Comment: I know, I already use NVARHAR but this is not a solution. I still get '?????' for non-English characters.

Comment: I'm the only one finds using unicode and N'' pattern simplier and most reliable than messing with collation?

Comment: Yes, that is okay for me too but they want me to do these things so I'm trying to figure something.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You have to use column's datatype `NVARCHAR` to insert unicode letters, also you have to use `N'value'` when inserting.

You can test it in following:

```
CREATE TABLE #test
(
    varcharCol varchar(40),
    nvarcharCol nvarchar(40)
)
INSERT INTO #test VALUES (N'иытание', N'иытание')

SELECT * FROM #test
```

**OUTPUT**

```
varcharCol  nvarcharCol
???????     иытание
```

As you see column of datatype `varchar` returning questionmarks `??????` and column of datatype `nvarchar` returning russian characters `иытание`.

---

**UPDATE**

Problem is that your database collation does not support russian letters.

1. In Object Explorer, connect to an instance of the SQL Server Database Engine, expand that instance, and then expand Databases.
2. Right-click the database that you want and click Properties.
3. Click the Options page, and select a collation from the Collation
   drop-down list.
4. After you are finished, click OK.

<kbd>[**MORE INFO**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175835.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)</kbd>

Comment: I know, I already search for the solution and found those examples but when I run these codes on SQL Server, I get '?????' for each of these codes. So I think maybe problem is SQL Server itself?

Comment: I just tested It on SQL-Server 2008 and It working. I provided OUTPUT  that I've tested. Provide your query.

Comment: I tried the exact same code that you wrote, but I got '?????' both nvarchar and varchar. I can't understand where is the problem.

Comment: @KeremCelebi It can be that because your collation of database not allow russian characters. In SSMS you can check It, by clicking right mouse button on database > properies. Check my updated answer.

Comment: Yes, that works fine, thank you. But now, when I want to use Arabic text, I must alter table with Arabic collation. I don't want that too. I just don't want to use N'text' for every query. So I wonder if is there any function or trigger for add automatic N in front of the text after text add.

Answer (score 8):

it would very difficult to put in comment i would recommend this link [Info](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/12475/n-prefix-before-string-in-transact-sql-query)

```
declare @test TABLE 
(
    Col1 varchar(40),
    Col2 varchar(40),
    Col3 nvarchar(40),
    Col4 nvarchar(40)
)
INSERT INTO @test VALUES
('иытание',N'иытание','иытание',N'иытание')

SELECT * FROM @test
```

**RESULT**

[image]

Answer (score 7):

To store and select **Unicode** character in database you have to use **NVARCHAR** instead of **VARCHAR**. To insert Unicode data you have to use **N**

See this link https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191200%28v=sql.105%29.aspx

> The n prefix for these data types comes from the ISO standard for National (Unicode) data types.

Answer (score 0):

Change type of your columns (containing Russian) from varchar to nvarchar.