# sql query by pool does not read kazakh letter

Tags: r, sql-server, pool

I am working on tool that will upload data to R from SQL server database and will do some fancy staff. Because of the fact there are more than one data source I am joining with pool package. I am facing a problem that it does not work when I query objects with kazakh letter. 
Here is the code example

```
poolDash <- dbPool(
         drv = odbc::odbc(),
         Driver = "ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server",
         Database = "database",
         Server = "server",
         UID = "user",
         PWD = "password")
 data <- pool::dbGetQuery(poolDash, "SELECT * from database 
                                     where ObjectName in ('Мәңгілік')")
```

The same query with ObjectName without kazakh letters work well.

Any help is welcome. Thank you in advance

Update: I have seen number of advices that column should be nvarchar type with limited size such as nvarchar (100). It is already nvarchar (100) and it helps me to work with russian letters but not with kazakh.

In this particular example kazakh letters are  "әң", secon and third letters.

Comment: just noticed you need to prefix with N'Мәңгілік'

Answer (score 2):

you can try to get data with `N` prefix.

```
"SELECT * from database 
         where ObjectName in (N'Мәңгілік')"
```

Comment: Related answer: [link]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32350950/select-cyrillic-character-in-sql