# Solve error in sql query with cyrillic symbols

Tags: sql, r

I have written sql query with cyrillic symbols:

```
"SELECT
                data.main_text as "Главный текст",
                _                _data.code as "Код",

                data.name as "Имена",
                data.other_name as "Другие имена"/*,
                data.days_from,
                to_date( data.days_from, 'YYYY-MM-DD'),
                data.days_to,
                to_date( data.days_to, 'YYYY-MM-DD'),
                data.**/
from
                database.info data
where
                24 = 24
                and current_date between to_date( data.days_from, 'YYYY-MM-DD') and to_date( data.days_to, 'YYYY-MM-DD')
                AND       COALESCE (data.code, '') != ''"
```

But it doesn't accept Cyrillic names (they are not red).What am i doing wrong here? And when i remove cyrillic symbols i get error (**ITS THE MAIN PROBLEM**):

```
Error: unexpected symbol in "                AND COALESCE"
```

Comment: Don't you have to handle double quotes like `\"Главный текст\"` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
"SELECT
                data.main_text as \"Главный текст\",
                data.code as \"Код\",

                data.name as \"Имена\",
                data.other_name as \"Другие имена\"
/*,
                data.days_from,
                to_date( data.days_from, 'YYYY-MM-DD'),
                data.days_to,
                to_date( data.days_to, 'YYYY-MM-DD'),
                data.*
*/
from
                database.info data
where
                24 = 24
                and current_date between to_date( data.days_from, 'YYYY-MM-DD') and to_date( data.days_to, 'YYYY-MM-DD')
                AND       COALESCE (data.code, '') != ''"
```

Comment: I also replaced `_                _data.code` with`data.code`

Answer (score 0):

> You have to use column's datatype NVARCHAR to insert unicode letters,
>   also you have to use N'value' when inserting.

[Select cyrillic character in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32350950/select-cyrillic-character-in-sql)

Comment: ok, and what about this error ```Error: unexpected symbol in "                AND COALESCE"``` ?

Comment: What is your column type?

Comment: which one do you mean?