# SQL: unable to get cyrillic character

Tags: sql, cyrillic

I found several topic open about how to insert correctly cyrillic word into the table.
But, my issue is different and I do not find answer here.

In my case, I've no issue to insert cyrillic word (and I'm using simple varchar, not nvarchar data_type)

But, when I do a Select, I do not get the cyrillic word, but ?????? instead.

Do you have any idea ?

Thanks

Comment: Use NVARCHAR. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32350950/select-cyrillic-character-in-sql

Comment: Database encoding? If you can you should use utf-8, then you are prepared for *any* characters (though cyrillic characters are multi-byte characters then). You need to make sure, too, that whatever encoding you use that the string passed to the sql-request is encoded accordingly – and when retrieving data from database you need to handle this encoding correctly as well (if need be, even convert!).

Comment: Not using `NVARCHAR` is just making life difficult for yourself, as you'll have to ensure your database uses a collation that can store Cyrillic characters (`Cyrillic_General_*`) and clients still have to take care of encoding issues on their end, which is a problem if the client too does not use Unicode throughout. For anything beyond plain ASCII (and that includes most Latin languages as well, really) `NVARCHAR` is just much less painful.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the issue: I had missed the AL32UTF8 as parameters on my oci_connect.